# In joomla 3.1.4 menu item does not show article content

Tags: joomla3.0

I have created a menu item "Contact us" in Joomla and its type is ***"single article"***. But when I click on this menu item in frontend, it doesn't show article content. Instead, it redirects me to the "Contact us.html" file, and the error `page not found` is shown.

When I access the article using `name` and `id` (through the link), it works properly.

What do I have to do in my template so the user could be redirected properly to the article?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla!™ 3.1.4 had security bugs and you should upgrade asap to 3.1.5 which is at this time the most recent version.
Then, check if your problem is still present and post here.